# Hosting two website in on one aws ec2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, hosting

I have a website currenty running on on a aws instance, and now I want to host another website also in same instance. I am running nginx as server. Do you know is it possible to host two website on that instance?

Thanks

Comment: This probably belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), so don't be surprised if it's suddenly moved there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You'll want to look into [Server Blocks](http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample), which are roughly the equivalent of VirtualHosts in Apache. See also [Basic Nginx Configuration](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/basic).

Comment: I solved the thing by listening same port with different server_name. Thanks for advice